# Probabilistic game

Tags: probability, combinatorial-game-theory

Suppose a rich person offers you $\$1000$ and says that you can participate in $1000$ rounds of this game:

In each round a coin is flipped and you get a $50$% return on the portion of your money that you risked if it lands on heads, or get a $40$% loss if it lands on tails. For example if you choose to risk all of your money in round one, then you'll either have $1500$ or $600$ dollars for rounds two. If you only risk half of it, then you'll either have $1250$ ($500+500*1.5$) or $800$($500+500*0.6$) dollars.

What is your best strategy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected value of your game is positive ($E[X]=0.5\alpha-0.4\alpha\ge 0$, where $\alpha$ is the amount of money bet) so the more you bet, the more you'll earn.

Moreover, betting all your money doesn't prevent you playing the $1000$ games since the result only affect a percentage of your bet, so the best strategy is to bet everything you have in the $1000$ rounds.

**EDIT** : I assume the coin is a fair coin.

Comment: Oh man, I thought this was a much better puzzle. I confused myself by the fact that in 1000 rounds on average you'll win 50% and lose 40% half the time, and 1.5^^500*0.6^^500 < 1. So your median outcome will be well under $1000, but you win so big that it compensates for all the losses.

Comment: Kind of interesting, that the player ends up with more money than he starts with only once per 7143 games, but the expected return is multiplying his money more than 10^^21st times.

Comment: You're right : in the two first round, if the player win and lose he will end up with less money than at the beginning but if you do the mean of 4 amounts of money that the player can win, it is above  $\$ 1000$. Maybe introducing a variable fear function of the current amount of money that the player has can make it more realistic.